# Angular Karma Test getting "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function" on a $scope.$parent function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While running `grunt test` on a Yeoman (1.0RC1) scaffolded Angular (1.0.7) app, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.$parent.userLoggedIn(true)')
```

`userLoggedIn()` is within a parent controller `index.js`. The function itself runs fine within the angular app.

This error doesn't occur on my other `$scope.$parent` boolean or strings variables in the controller, so it's related directly to calling functions within a parent.

I'm thinking that I'm either using `$scope.$parent` the wrong way or that I need to define my `index.js` controller in the test, but Karma testing documentation is sporadic, so it's hard to know.

EDIT: Here is the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('uiApp')
  .controller('LookupCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    $scope.$parent.userLoggedIn(true);

  }]);
```

Here is the test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: LookupCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('uiApp'));

  var LookupCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    LookupCtrl = $controller('LookupCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });

});
```

(Yes I know I'm just using the default `awesomeThings` test for now. I'm new to Angular testing).

Comment: Could you please provide your code for the testing controller.

Comment: In general that just means that you're trying to use a property name to find a function, but the object you're working with doesn't have such a property. Thus, you're trying to use `undefined` as a function, and it's not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the controller a `rootScope`, which doesn't have `$parent` (it's the root).
Change your controller code to call it correctly (using the prototype chain) and you'll be fine by just passing `{my: props}` as an object.

Comment: I got it to work, but I'm not sure I did it properly.

I added my IndexCtrl before the LookupCtrl in the test and called the root scope within there.

Comment: I added my `IndexCtrl` before the `LookupCtrl` in the test and called the `var scope = $rootScope.$new()` with `$scope: scope.$new()` within there. After that, in the `LookupCtrl`, I just made another new scope with `$scope: scope.$new()`

Comment: Can someone put a fiddle together?? I can't make sense of what's being suggested here.