# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'angular.element(window).width()')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi I have a pretty complex app that I have been writing Karma unit tests for. I have a lot of tests that were written and running sucessfully but then I changed a few things in the app and now I am getting tons of errors. Been staring at it for hours and can't figure it out.

Error I get:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'angular.element(window).width()')
    at /Users/Desktop/app/scripts/app.js:9
    at invoke (/Users/Desktop/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869)
    at /Users/Desktop/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715
```

My config file looks like this

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-ui-date/src/date.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/src/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/d3/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/nvd3/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularjs-nvd3-directives/src/directives/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/ng-grid/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/ng-grid/build/*.js',
  'app/bower_components/ng-grid/plugins/*.js',
  'app/scripts/app.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'app/scripts/***/**/*.js',
  'test/client/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [
'app/bower_components/*/angular-scenario.js', 
'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/src/compat.js',
'app/bower_components/angularjs-nvd3-directives/src/directives/intro.js',
'app/bower_components/angularjs-nvd3-directives/src/directives/outro.js'
],

// web server port
port: 8080,

// level of logging
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// Start this browser
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

//Coverage Options
preprocessors: {
  'app/scripts/**.js': 'coverage'
},
reporters: ['dots', 'coverage']

});
};
```

The controller I'm testing:

```
angular.module("vizApp").controller("BasicSearchCtrl", function ($rootScope, $scope, SearchService) {
    "use strict";

    $scope.searchContent = null;

    $scope.$watch("searchContent", function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    SearchService.setBasicSearch($scope.searchContent);
    });

});
```

And the test I'm writing is:

```
describe("Controller: BasicSearchCtrl", function () {
    "use strict";
    var scope, BasicSearchController, httpBackend, searchSerivce;

    //load the controller"s module
    beforeEach(module("vizApp"));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
        httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
        });
    });

//initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {

    // create a new child scope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    scope.SearchService = $injector.get("SearchService");

    //create a new instance of basic search controller
    BasicSearchController = $controller("BasicSearchCtrl", { $scope: scope });

}));

//check the initial state of the search content
it("very basic search", function () {

    expect(scope.searchContent).toBeUndefined;
    expect(scope.SearchService.basicSearch).toBeUndefined;

});
```

But I keep getting this cryptic error...about line 9 on app.js but app.js looks like this so I dont get it.

```
angular.module('vizApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.router',
'nvd3ChartDirectives',
'ngGrid',
'ui.sortable',
'ui.date'
]).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

'use strict';

// For any unmatched url, redirect to /
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the test in a debugger, the chrome console for example?

Comment: Yes, I have...but it's tough to understand where I'm having problems. It seems like everything crashes the moment my controller tries to inject the httpbackend

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385842/angular-karma-test-getting-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-a-scop

Comment: I have seen this before but the solution here seemed to be to inject the parent controller before injecting the controller you're testing...however, in my app, I don't think mybasicsearch controller has a parent controller?

Comment: Remove the coverage preprocessors in karma config first, to get the correct line number of the error.

Comment: Ahh apparently the error is actually this in my test
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://server:80/api/metrics

Answer (score 1):

width() is not a supported by angular, which internally relies on jqLite https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element.

You would have to either include jquery and use jquery's width() function or better still inject Angular's $window service and use $window[0].innerWidth or $window[0].offsetWidth or $window[0].clientWidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jquery instead of jqlite, then your mock config is the problem:

Just move the jquery.js to the first position in the file list. If jquery is after angular.js, you'll just get a jqlite object which doesn't have viewport methods.